# Word for the "life/world" outside phone calls, text messages, and the Internet?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> She ignored my phone calls, text messages, and emails. As for [...], she also seemed to have
>   taken measures: she quit our shared classes and stopped
>   frequenting the places where we used to cross paths.

I searched for the antonyms of [virtual](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/virtual) but I think they sound a bit weird. As for real life/world? As for actual life/world?

Comment: Most people would call it *the **real** world* (with stress on the word "real" to emphasize that this is in contrast to the online/virtual world).

Comment: As for ***the rest*** , she seemed to have taken measures :...

Comment: "offline" is a possibility, or "offline world". (made as a comment not an answer as I can't be bothered to find any links)

Comment: @AndyT - although 'offline' is the opposite of 'online' as 'virtual', the problem with 'offline' is that it describes absence online rather than presence in the real world. When we say 'offline', we still imply 'online' in the sense of absence.

Comment: In some cases, the opposite of "digital" is "analog".

Comment: Wouldn't want to answer because it's not really correct, but I've heard it called the Outernet in fun, FWIW.

Comment: What about "__non-virtual__ reality" as an antonym of "virtual"?

Comment: There are many things you could say with different flavours for whatever the effect you want... "in the physical world", "in the real world", "outside of cyberspace", "as for face-to-face", "as for the world of scents and sounds"....

Comment: I'm with @Josh61- "As for ***the rest of her life*** she also seemed to have taken measures..."

Comment: @GEdgar But "analog" can still refer to something electronic in nature. "As for [the analog world], she also seemed to have taken measures" sounds to me like the world being referred to is one full of old radio sets and cathode ray tubes.. :P

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The cyber-cool among us use the phrase *[meatspace](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=meatspace)* to refer to the physical world.

[UD]

Comment: I've also heard IRL but it doesn't sound as nice.

Comment: "unplugged" is what I hear other parents/teachers use.

Comment: Love it but can I think it sounds crude. Like *meat market*, or *treated like meat.* Understand that a mishearing might lead to offense.

Comment: @geoO I've always understood it to be rather deliberately crude. It's also definitely not something I'd expect a majority of people to know, as it's from techie/cyberpunk vernacular, rather than a general term.

Comment: Not only is it intended (in part) to be crude, it goes way back. From Gibson's "Neuromancer"  (1984): "In the bars he'd frequented as a cowboy hotshot, the elite stance involved a certain relaxed contempt for the flesh. The body was meat." This is, of course, literature rather than (gasp! the irony!) the real world, but it's seminal literature. See also Terry Bisson's "They're Made Out of Meat" http://www.terrybisson.com/page6/page6.html

Comment: I have never heard this phrase. Does that mean I'm not cool?

Comment: Well but "Meatspace" or IRL assume the virtual world is the one that's real.  If that's what you're going for then use these.

Comment: @CactusWoman - See how cool you can become by paying attention on ELU?

Comment: [The "Meatspace" domains have all, of course, been reserved.](http://whoisrequest.org/domain/meatspace.com)   (^_^)

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't heard this word before, but my initial thought when I saw the question was "meatosphere" :)

Comment: This answer would be better if you gave more than a link to UD. I mean, some citation of actual use in a real setting would be nice.

Answer (score 20):

Consider re-working the phrase to accommodate **In Person**

eg "She seemed to have taken measures to avoid me **in person** as well -- she quit our shared classes..."

Comment: I give a +1 for 'in person' - a great alternative but it is not quite opposite for  'calls, text messages, emails', otherwise, what is the opposite of 'in person'?

Answer (score 20):

**Virtual** is a one-word description for 'phone, messages, emails'.

**Real life** or **real world** describes the opposite.

> As for **the real world**, she also seemed to have taken measures: she quit our
> shared classes and stopped frequenting the places where we used to
> cross paths.

Also, [**Collins American English Dictionary**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/real?showCookiePolicy=true) has **the real** as noun

> *noun*
>
> 8. anything that actually exists, or reality in general *(with the)*

So a shorter and more colloquial usage will be

> As for **the real**, she also seemed to have taken measures: she quit our
> shared classes and stopped frequenting the places where we used to
> cross paths.

**An update on 'real' for phone vs 'virtual' for computer.**

Some people insist that a phone conversation is real rather than virtual (see Josh61's comment below). Also, some marketing experts relate phone communication to real as in this article, 'Virtual vs. Real Life Communication: What Do Workers Prefer?' on [The Business News Daily](http://www.businessnewsdaily.com/4039-virtual-real-life-communication.html):

> Forty percent of workers say they worked with someone for an extended
> period of time without ever **meeting that co-worker in person** or
> **talking on the phone**.

But from the point of view of pure physics as science, the real is tangible; consider this example on [Michigan State University](https://www.pa.msu.edu/courses/2000fall/PHY232/lectures/lenses/images.html) website:

> **Real images** are those where light actually converges, whereas **virtual
> images** are locations from where light appears to have converged.

Finally in the OP's given example, from the point of view of the guy, everything is virtual except for face-to face meeting.

Comment: Would a computer or a phone call not be part of real life?

Comment: @Josh61 - a great question, I have researched on this and updated my answer.

Comment: I think anything using "real" in this sense is quickly going to seem dated if not like complete luddism. Imagine someone taking about "real wagons" or "real carriages" in an age of cars.

Comment: I most frequently hear real life and IRL to refer to something not on the Internet. this answer has my vote.

Answer (score 14):

In the good old days of the internet the abbreviation IRL (in real life) was the term that was always used.  It was popular enough that people would say "IRL" IRL

Comment: I like this the most. Three letter initialisms just sound so stilted. If there were a proper acronym (like scuba or radar) that flowed it would be perfect. Still, in writing and not in speech it works quite well. You get my upvote.

Comment: ... what do you mean by "was"?  The use of "IRL" is incredibly common today.

Answer (score 11):

The opposite of the **virtual** world would be the **physical** world.
I also like **face-to-face** or **"in person"**.

Answer (score 2):

The **Outernet**
Whilst it is not a real word, people will know what you mean.

Comment: If you had used that word with me, I would not have known what you meant.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean.

Comment: 'inter' is not an opposite of 'outer'. 'Outernet' would be valid as a match of 'innernet' which does not exist.

Comment: @javaNoobs, it doesn't need to be linguistically sound, as it's just a slang word based on a pun (as "internet" is often pronounced "innernet").

Comment: @Nicole If you want people to understand what you mean when you make up a word, you'd better aim for something that can be properly pieced together from its linguistic meaning.  "Outernet" sounds, to me, like some sort of network separate from the Internet but still in the digital world.

Comment: I didn't make it up. I'm not even the one who wrote this answer. But I've heard it plenty of places, and clearly Mutantoe has too. You can't dismiss every slang word that you don't personally use. If enough people use a word to mean something, then that's what the word means, whether you like it or not. That's why some dictionaries have listed "figuratively" as a definition of "literally."

Comment: @Nicole Very true, use of words that don't exist contributes to the evolution of any language. Yak "selfie" for example.

Comment: I've heard this word often in the internet, especially in memes. There is a subculture in which this is a well-understood word.

Comment: Holy crap! I was just toying with the idea of posting this as an answer, with exactly the same caveat: as far as I knew, that word existed only inside my head. I'm delighted to hear that other people have been using it. ^_^

Comment: @MatthewRead, what you say may be true for neologisms in technical language, which are often coined in a somewhat deliberate way, but I don't think the evolution of everyday speech follows such neat rules. To catch on, a neologism doesn't have to make sense; it just has to be natural and compelling in some way. The fact that I and probably many others have come up with *outernet* independently suggests that it's natural and compelling in exactly that way.

Comment: Further proof that this word is indeed used and understood by a certain group of people: On Urban Dictionary, its definition of "external reality, unlike the internet, which is the internal reality" has 45 thumbs up.

Answer (score 2):

Another expression that is similar to IRL is AFK, Away From Keyboard. Not sure how applicable it is to this case, but I thought that it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

*Meatspace* is probably the most widely-recognized answer.  But if you're looking for something equally nerdy and a bit less metaphorical, consider [the Big Room](http://www.hacker-dictionary.com/terms/Big-Room,-the):

> The extremely large room with the blue ceiling and intensely bright light . . .

Answer (score 1):

In written exchange I've usually seen it expressed as IRL ("in real life"), but (unfortunately) I all-too-often think of it as OTL -- "off the leash".
;-)

Answer (score -6):

Routine.  In your example, routine looks like a good fit.

```
    routine
    a sequence of actions regularly followed; a fixed program.
```